# Unable to bind data in React Js to load Tab content dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i want bind state in react in map, below is my code,

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');

    var configtabs = {
        ctabs: [
            {
                key: 31,
                id: "analysis_method_tab",
                title: "Analysis Method",
                content: "Loading Analysis Method Content . . ."
            },
            {
                key: 32,
                id: "categorization_tab",
                title: "Categorization",
                content: "Loading Categorization Content . . ."
            },
            {
                key: 33,
                id: "custom_ngs_template",
                title: "Custom NGS Template",
                content: "Loading Custom NGS Template Content . . ."
            }
        ]
    };
    var HomeTabContent = React.createClass({
        render() {
            return(
                <div> On Click Home Content</div>
            );
        }
    });
    var AnalysisWorkflowTabContent = React.createClass({
        render() {
            return(
                <div> On Click Analysis Workflow Content </div>
            );
        }
    });
    var SubTabsHolderComponent = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
            return {
              selSubTabkey:31
            };
          },
           handleSelectSubTab(selSubTabkey) {
                //alert('selected subtab' + selSubTabkey);
                this.setState({selSubTabkey});
            },
        render() {
         var Tabs = ReactBootstrap.Tabs,
             Tab = ReactBootstrap.Tab;

            return(

                <Tabs activeKey={this.state.selSubTabkey} animation={true} tabWidth={2} paneWidth={5} position="left" onSelect={this.handleSelectSubTab}>
                    {
                        this.props.subTabs.map(function (ctab) {
                            return (
                                <Tab eventKey={ctab.key} id={ctab.id} title={ctab.title}> 
                                {   
                                     ctab.key===this.state.selSubTabKey && <EachSubTabContent subTabKey={ctab.key} id={ctab.id} title={ctab.title}/>
                                }
                                </Tab>
                            );
                        },this)
                    }
                </Tabs>
            );
        }
    });
    var EachSubTabContent = React.createClass({
        render() {

            var subTabKey=this.props.key;
            var id=this.props.id;
            var title=this.props.title;

            return(
                <div> get data for '{title}' tab and then create its components like tree or accordian.for each accordian onclick it will fetch sub data like for track it will fetch track data and will display it in table </div>
            );
        }
    });
    const SureCallMainTabs = React.createClass({

         getInitialState() {
            return {
              selkey: 1
            };
          },

          handleSelect(selkey) {
            //alert('selected ' + selkey);
            this.setState({selkey});

          },

          render() {
            var ctabs = this.props.configtabs.ctabs;
            var stabs = this.props.supptabs.stabs;

             var Tabs = ReactBootstrap.Tabs,
                Tab=ReactBootstrap.Tab;

                return (     

                <Tabs activeKey={this.state.selkey} animation={false} position="top" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                    <Tab eventKey={1} id="home_tab" title="Home">
                        { 
                            this.state.selkey === 1 &&  <HomeTabContent />
                        }
                    </Tab>

                    <Tab eventKey={2} id="analysis_workflow" title="Analysis Workflow">
                        { 
                            this.state.selkey === 2 &&  <AnalysisWorkflowTabContent />
                        }
                    </Tab>

                    <Tab eventKey={3} id="configure_setting" title="Configure Setting" >
                        { 
                            this.state.selkey === 3 &&  <SubTabsHolderComponent subTabs = {ctabs}/>
                        }
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
                );
          }
    });

ReactDOM.render(<SureCallMainTabs  configtabs={configtabs} supptabs={supptabs}/>, document.getElementById("react_tabs"));
```

but its not working, can you please help me out?
and one more thing, how to align all tabs in right side horizontally and can we set icon to each tab?

Comment: You need to provide more info about *what*'s not working.

Comment: Don't dump a bunch of code and expect us to tell you what to do. explain the problem.

Comment: I have added independent component code, if we run it then you will see the problem is content of sub tabs is not getting displayed.

Comment: this.props.subTabs.map(function (ctab) { return ( <Tab eventKey={ctab.key} id={ctab.id} title={ctab.title}> { ctab.key===this.state.selSubTabKey && <EachSubTabContent subTabKey={ctab.key} id={ctab.id} title={ctab.title}/> } </Tab> ); },this)       from this code I am unable to use this.state.selSubTabKey in map loop.

Comment: @thangngoc89 can you please help me out?

Comment: Simple. You're inside a closure. You need to bind it first or simply use arrow function